# CSS create border on one side with sharp square edges

Tags: html, css

everyone, I am trying to add border to one side of a `a` element, however, when I add it to one side it give it a sharp diagonal edge:

[image]

I am trying to remove the sharp edge and make it a square.

I have tried using pseudo-elemnts to achieve this but I have had no luck:

Currently, I am using:

```
a{
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) !important;
  border-left-width: 0;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position: relative;
}

a::before{
  border-left: 2px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9) !important;
  border-radius: 0px;
  position:absolute;
  content:'';
}
```

But this is still giving me the results below. How can I do this successfully?

Comment: Don't use a border on the pseudo-element, make the pseudo-element 2px wide etc.

Comment: Or make sure you set the other borders to `0px`

Comment: Also you spelled "position" wrong for `position: relative;`

Comment: I have tried doing that but it just removes the border @Paulie_D

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the **shortest code** necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself** preferably in a [**Stack Snippet**](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/).  See [**How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/reprex)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See if this works for you:

```
box-shadow: -10px 0 0 0 black;
```

Just that, no borders.